# Swap div content from the same text link

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am having trouble resolving an issue using traditional JavaScript and was wondering if there is an easy solution using jQuery. I've searched the web and haven't been able to find anything that does exactly what i want to do.

So.. this is what i want to achieve:
I have 2 div's with content, first one is displayed, second is hidden. 
Below and outside of these div's i have a single text link which when first clicked, will swap the content on the first div with the second div. When clicked a second time i want it to  swap back to first div and so on.. It should toggle between the 2 div's on each onClick every time i click the text link.

To put a bit more context to it, my div's contain a form with 2 labels and text inputs. In the first div the labels say To: and From: In the second div, the order is simply flipped to say From: and then To: 
Below the inputs i have a text link that will allow the user to switch the order around to From: and To:

**To:**
text input
**From:**
text input
- Text link -

When the text link is clicked i want the content replaced with this:

**From:**
text input
**To:**
text input

**Here is an example of what i've tried** - *Note: This is very close to how i want it except when the link is clicked a second time, nothing happens*

```
<script type="text/javascript">

<code>function hideID(objID){
var element = document.getElementById(objID);
element.style.display="none";
}
function showID(objID){
var element = document.getElementById(objID);
element.style.display="block";
}</code>

</script>
```

```
<div id="div1">content 1</div>
```

```
<div id="div2" style="display:none;">content 2</div>
```

```
<a href="" onClick="hideID('div1');showID('div2'); return false;">Reverse</a>
```

If anyone has any ideas, i would be very greatful
kind regards
~declan

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to do it without using JQuery:

```
<a href="#" onclick="hideShow('div1', 'div2');return false;">

<script language='javascript'>
function hideShow(divOneId, divTwoId)
{
 var divOne = document.getElementById(divOneId);
 var divTwo  = document.getElementById(divTwoId);


divOne.style.display =   (divOne.style.display == 'none') ? 'block' : 'none';
divTwo.style.display =   (divTwo.style.display == 'none') ? 'block' : 'none';


}

</script>
```

Comment: wow! that worked perfectly. I feel a tad bit embarrassed now with my level or lack of knowledge with all this stuff. 
I'll also try out the jQuery examples posted above.

thanks everyone for the speedy replies :-)

Comment: Don't be embarrassed :).  A lot of people here have been doing a long time, and there's a lot to learn.

Answer (score 2):

Using jQuery, and based on your code that you've tried for simply showing/hiding the divs, how about (untested):

```
$(document).ready( function() {
  $("#div1").show();
  $("#div2").hide();
});

$("a#someIDhere").click( function() {
  $("#div1").toggle();
  $("#div2").toggle();
});
```

tagging the `<a>` tag with an ID that you can use above?

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#yourReverseAnchor').click(function(e) {
    var swap = $('div1').html();
    $('div1').html($('div2').html());
    $('div2').html(swap);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's quite simple using jQuery:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function ()
{
    var a = $('#a'),
        b = $('#b');

    function swap()
    {
        var a_html = a.html();
        a.html(b.html());
        b.html(a_html);
    }

    $('#swap').click(swap);
});
</script>

<div id="a">first</div>
<div id="b">second</div>
<a id="swap">swap</a>
```

Comment: That didn't work for me.. even tried adding a href="#" to the a link. Is it working for you? Perhaps i'm leaving something out. And yes, i am referencing jquery.1.3.2.min.js in my code

Answer (score 0):

With jQuery this becomes simply:

```
<div id="div1">content 1</div>
<div id="div2" style="display:none;">content 2</div>
<a href="#" id="toggle">Reverse</a>
```

and

```
$(function() {
  $("#toggle").click(function() {
    var div1 = $("#div1");
    if (div1.is(":hidden")) {
      div1.show();
      $("#div2").hide();
    } else {
      div1.hide();
      $("#div2").show();
    }
    return false;
  });
});
```

There's no point manipulating the DOM in this case unless there's something you're not telling us. It's easier just to hide and show as required.

Comment: That didn't work also.. i'm begining to think i'm not doing something right elsewhere in my code

Comment: Run it in Firefox and look at your Javascript/Firebug debug window. You might have some syntax error stopping execution or something.

Comment: Ok, completely my fault. for whatever reason when linking to google's jQuery js it works. Previously i was linking locally and still can't see what was wrong with the path but, it didn't work.
Thanks for posting that example - works perfectly!