# DIV swap for multiple DIVs

Tags: html, swap

[Swap div content from the same text link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1532653/swap-div-content-from-the-same-text-link)

That post has almost what i need to answer my question.  It works fine for two DIVs, what if I have quite a few.  How would you change the function without having to keep adding declaration lines for more variables?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you can use jQuery, you could try something like this: http://jsfiddle.net/k9JC4/6/

**Html:**

```
<a class="que">Question 1</a>
<div class="ans">
    Answer 1
</div>
<a class='que'>Question 2</a>
<div class='ans'>
    Answer 2
</div>
<a class='que'>Question 3</a>
<div class='ans'>
    Answer 3
</div>
```

**Css:**

```
.ans
{
    display: none;
}

a
{
    display: block;
    color: blue;
}
```

**Js:**

```
$(function(){
    $('.que').click(function(ev){
        ev.preventDefault();

        $('.ans').hide();
        $(this).next('.ans').show();
    });
});
```

How this works is that when you click on a link with the class *.que* jQuery will find the next sibling element with the class *.ans*. It will hide all other *.ans* class members then show the sibling found.

Comment: how do i post my code on this thing? i can show you what i mean